# circe json auto derivation for case classes with mixin traits or other options

Tags: json, scala, circe

I was using circe for awhile and all is mostly ok when you work within the standard examples. Thought one thing I'm struggling is to get more reusability when dealing with case classes. Here is one case:

```
trait EntityResponse extends Entity
{
  def meta: MetaEntityResponse
}

case class GetProductResponse(id: Int,
                              name: String,                              
                              price: BigDecimal
                             )
case class GetProductListResponse(items: Seq[GetProductResponse],
                                  meta: MetaPaging)
```

I'm using the GetProductResponse in multiple contexts as an example:
1. If I return a standalone product I would like to mixin the EntityResponse
2. When I return a product list then I don't need to have a mixin for each product as its added on a list object

Maybe there is a better way to do it, as long as I don't have to duplicate same case class twice 1 with trait and 1 without it, which seems the only option at this point.